# How to import BaseGameUtils in .NET?

Tags: .net, xamarin, leaderboard

How to import BaseGameUtils (https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/tree/master/BasicSamples/libraries/BaseGameUtils) in Xamarin or Visual Studio Android Application Project?

Doesn't exist .NET DLL? No one used it yet? Or no need BaseGameUtils for leaderboards?

I watched this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU0n43LtqCI

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a native library from Xamarin you create a [binding](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/) for it.

Alternately, you could just hand-port the code to C#.  The code you linked to is only three classes of a few hundred lines and may not be unreasonably big to translate.